# React redirect - Redirect component on react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to build a simple component that will make one API call and after 2 seconds will redirect to another page.
For that, I tried to use the Redirect component from react-router-dom,
but the import fails

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
```

I'm getting the error: "react-router-dom has no exported member 'Redirect'."

version "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `<Redirect />` in v5 has been replaced by `<Navigate />` which can also be used in the same way.

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return <Navigate to="/home" />;
}
```